# Django Channels message life time

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

I have some (possibly huge) amount of JSON data I need to push into Django Channel. The data has very small required lifetime (2-3 seconds is enough). I use Redis as backend.

What is default message lifetime? 
Is it possible to specify life time of the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to resolve my issue without patching asgi_redis code for customer expiry of message.

I created two channel layers in my configuration. Then I set desired short expiry to the second channel layer. All short live time messages now passed and handled by this channel layer consumer.

Answer (score 1):

By default there's no limit to the lifetime, but you can set one by using SETEX instead of SET:

```
SETEX mykey 10 "Hello"
```

or by using SET with the EX flag:

```
SET mykey "Hello" EX 10
```

Comment: How to do this using Django Channels?

Comment: Yes, this option is set for all messages in the channel, but I need to setup expiration just for part of messages. I understood it's possible to setup two channel layers with different value of expiry option.

Comment: Another way is to create second channel layer with short expiry setting and use it for short life time messages.